# React JS with Rails - Accessing JSON data with URL

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, reactjs

I'm learning how to use React JS with my Rails app. 
*Disclaimer: This is the first time I am messing around with JS!*

I'm following a talk by [Michael Chan at Rails Conf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTSsZrub5iE). Everything works beautifully until I hit the CommentsContainer part, where he fetches the comments data from a Rails route. I am trying to the same thing, except on a simple Songs controller (generated with a scaffold, having name and artist as the attribute).

I am getting stuck at the part where he fetches this data with the path, I end up with a 500 error page when I try to run the code. I don't know how to debug my React code, since the browser console is just showing a 500 error.

Here's my view,

```
<%= react_component "SongsContainer", { songsPath: songs_path } %>
```

And here's my React code,

```
var SongsContainer = React.createClass({
componentWillMount(){
    this.fetchSongs();
    setInterval(this.fetchSongs, 1000);
},

fetchSongs() {
    $.getJSON(
        this.props.songsPath,
        (data) => this.setState({songs: data});
    );
},

getInitialState() {
    return { songs: [] };
},

render() {
    return <Songs songs={this.state.songs} />;
}
});
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated! I'm just looking at this 500 page not knowing what to do.

EDIT: Adding Server log

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-08-11 18:19:30 +0530
Processing by SongsController#index as HTML
  Rendered songs/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 373ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (10:41)):
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>Albums</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
    9: <body>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___3071413699732960348_70238909518380'
```

Comment: The server log from the console doesn't show anything? Also, there is a network tab in your developer tools that shows more information about requests being made. Try looking at it too.

Comment: Please check my update!

Comment: Well, it says it is a syntax error in layout file. Try removing this turbolink stuff, as you are using React you don't need it anyway. Remove the two "data-turbolinks-track" => true hash key/value pairs from your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb .

Comment: That made the error disappear. But now my view is not showing any data. I have a record in the DB though.

Comment: Now, does the server log shows the query being made? Something like `SELECT * FROM songs` or whatever you are fetching.

Comment: Then you have a problem in your controller. Maybe your index action is doing nothing.

Comment: But when I visit it as a HTML request, Rails is showing me data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86699/discussion-between-swaathi-k-and-murifox).

Answer (score 0):

Finally after lots of struggle, I found a solution!

1. Remove Turbolinks from application.html.
2. Replace the $.getJSON function with this,

   $.ajax({
      url: this.props.songsPath,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({songs: data});
      }.bind(this)
    });

Now, I really don't know much about JS, so I don't know why this works, but it just does! Cheers.

Comment: As error says, there was syntax error.  `(data) => this.setState({songs: data});` - see the last char on this line. You shouldn't use `;` in the params of method, there is no such syntax in js.