# Unable to parse JSON from Rails server with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to parse the JSON data rendered from my Rails server with Javascript, however I keep facing an unknown error. I am just starting out with JS, but have good experience with Rails.

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction!
[image: Chrome Console]

EDIT: Added code
I'm trying to use React with my Rails application. And when I try to parse the JSON data, the server crashes, so that's why I tried to debug in the console and faced the same error.

Here's my view,

```
<%= react_component "SongsContainer", { songsPath: songs_path } %>
```

And here's my React code,

```
var SongsContainer = React.createClass({
componentWillMount(){
    this.fetchSongs();
    setInterval(this.fetchSongs, 1000);
},

fetchSongs() {
    $.getJSON(
        this.props.songsPath,
        (data) => this.setState({songs: data});
    );
},

getInitialState() {
    return { songs: [] };
},

render() {
    return <Songs songs={this.state.songs} />;
}
});
```

And my controller is very basic,

```
render :json => Song.first.to_json
```

EDIT: Error when trying to use getJSON,
[image]

Comment: Your json looks clean to me. Can you update the question with the received json and the code that manipulates it in js.

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: I just updated my question. I'm just trying to parse the JSON, and then move onto more complicated things later. But I am unable to parse the JSON.

Comment: You don't need to parse it yourself. Since you use "getJSON" jQuery knows this and has done it for you. "data" is an object.

Comment: Can you please check my updated question?

Comment: I'm guessing... but I'm wondering if there's a pluralisation problem here. looks like your Songs component may expect an array of songs... and you're only returning a single song...

Comment: I ended up solving the parent issue, though I don't know how. It would be great if someone could explain it to me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942177/react-js-with-rails-accessing-json-data-with-url

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error is not in the invocation but rather in the syntax.
according to getJSON jquery documentation you should pass the data as a string.

Have you tried passing the argument this way?

```
fetchSongs() {
    $.getJSON(
        this.props.songsPath,
        this.setState({songs: data})
    );
}
```